# Get shared O365 calendars with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to get information (events and tasks) about shared calendars with Graph API. 
In my Office365 account, I have several shared calendars ( calendars that other people have shared with me ) and I have any kind of privileges on those: from the client or from the browser I can read/write appointments and task. So I don't understand why I can't retrieve information about those shared calendars with Graph API. I tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
```

but I get only my personal calendars, and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendarGroups/{shared-calendar-group-id}/calendars
```

but I get an empty response.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get shared calendars

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user id who shared the calendar to you')/calendars
```

[official guidline](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#calendars)

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because I tried with that endpoint but I get an error response ( because I haven't the permission to acces to other people calendars).

Comment: This is correct. Follow the guideline Lee has linked too. It explains how this works.

Comment: the link is a 404 now